# Why is API response with binary data changing characters

Tags: java, rest, character-encoding, binary

I'm at a loss here. I have an API that returns binary data. The problem is, when the binary data is received, it's slightly different that what was sent causing the data to not be consumed.

I've tried in C# and Java. The latest code snippet from Java is:

```
  private NanoHTTPD.Response response() throws IOException
  {

    byte[] data = readFileData(file); //this is a file with binary data, read into a byte array

    return newChunkedResponse(NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK, "application/octet-stream", new ByteArrayInputStream(data) );
  }
```

The client is expecting application/octet-stream. I've converted to base64 before sending and printed it to compare with actual response data. Comparing the two shows differences. A hex dump also shows differences.

Hexdump

00000250  00 02 00 00 00 43 00 6b  0b 09 24 4c a5 2b 3f af  |.....C.k..$L.+?.|

00000250  00 02 00 00 00 43 00 6b  0b 09 24 4c a5 2b 81 af  |.....C.k..$L.+..|

90% of the data seems to match. I can't figure out why some data is getting changed. I've tried different charsets: UTF-8, ANSI.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: 
I've tried with and without charsets, and I still get data different than the source.

I just tried the below, and same issue.

`byte[] data= Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
return newFixedLengthResponse(NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK, "application/octet-stream", new ByteArrayInputStream(data), data.length);`

Comment: “I've tried different charsets…” And that’s probably the issue.  Binary files don’t have a charset, and converting bytes to and from characters will corrupt the original bytes.  I’m not sure what `readFileData` does, but you may want to use [Files.readAllBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) instead.

Comment: Edited my response. That was not the problem. I'm still seeing characters different.

Comment: Please show the code which reads and saves the response.  I suspect a charset is somehow in use, as `?` is a common replacement character (on Windows at least) when a byte is encountered which is not valid in the charset.  0x81 is not valid in ASCII, UTF-8, or ISO 8859-x.